# Why is this Insert Statement throwing an error?

Tags: php, mysql

I really dont know why this statement isnt working with mysql... do you have any idea? Am I blind?

Error Message:

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES ('Wampanoag Country Club', 'West Hartford', 'CT', '', '1', '', '')' at line 9

> ```
> INSERT INTO companies 
> (companies.firmname,
> companies.city,
> companies.state,
> companies.zip,
> companies.country,
> companies.address1,
> companies.address2 
> VALUES ('Wampanoag Country Club',
> 'West Hartford',
> 'CT',
> '',
> '1',
> '',
> '')
> ```

Comment: add a `)` before VALUES

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing ) after companies.address2 and before VALUES

Answer (score 1):

Missing a closing )

```
 INSERT INTO companies 
                     (
                      companies.firmname, 
                      companies.city,
                      companies.state,
                      companies.zip,
                      companies.country,
                      companies.address1,
                      companies.address2
                     ) <-- need this 
VALUES 
                   (
                     'Wampanoag Country Club',
                     'West Hartford',
                     'CT',
                     '',
                     '1',
                     '',
                     ''
                   )
```